# Internet Explorer won't play my video unless the user click compatibility mode.

Tags: internet-explorer, video

I have a website:

www.nurseresumetips.com

I'm using Flowplayer to play a h.264 encoded video. This works on all browzers including ios devices.

The problem is with Internet Explorer. I'm running ie 9 and the video won't play unless the user turns on compatibility mode.

I'm using a Wordpress plugin JVPress.

I want to wave a magic wand and make is so my video plays automatically in any version of IE 7 and above.

And advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing the compatibility mode with:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />`

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc817574.aspx) for details.